# Virtual attributes in ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Is it possible to add virtual attributes to a ngResource?
I created a service like this

```
app.factory('Person', ['$resource', function($resource) {

  return $resource('api/path/:personId', {
    personId: '@_id'
      }, {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        }
      });
}])
```

`Person` has an attribute `name` and an attribute `surname`.
I want to retrive the `fullname` by adding a virtual attribute `fullname` returning `resource.name + resource surname`.
I know I could add it in the controller, but adding it to the service it will make it much more portable.
I tried something like this

```
app.factory('Person', ['$resource', function($resource) {

  return $resource('api/path/:personId', {
    personId: '@_id'
      }, {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        },
    fullname: function(resource){
      return resource.name + ' ' + resource.surname;
    }
  });
 });
}])
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [intercepting](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#interceptors) the response from the Person resource and augment the response. Like this:

```
app.factory('Person', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  function getFullName(){
      return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
  };

  return $resource('api/path/:personId', {
    personId: '@_id'
      }, {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        },
        'get': {method:'GET', isArray:false,interceptor:{
              'response': function(response) {
                  response.fullname = getFullName; //augment the response with our function
                  return response;
               }
         }}
      });
}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the docs, `$resource` returns a constructor. You can leverage the usual `prototype` of the constructor to add members, i.e.:

```
var Person = $resource('api/path/:personId', {
            personId: '@_id'
        }, {
            update: { method: 'PUT' }
        }); // same as the 1st snippet from the question

Person.prototype.xxxx = ...;

return Person; // from your Angular service
```

In the previous example `xxxx` can be anything normally allowed in a prototype. If what you want is actually a derived property, i.e. a JS property that will always reflect the `name` and `surname` properties, then you need a fairly recent browser that supports `Object.defineProperty()` and replace the `Person.prototype` line above with:

```
Object.defineProperty(
    Person.prototype,
    "fullname",
    {get: function() { return this.name + " " + this.surname; }}
);
```

Comment: It works like any other property but you can't set a value to it (unless you specify a setter)

Comment: Of course not, and it should not, since this is a derived (calculated) property. A setter can be defined if needed by some other use case though.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you ^^, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: This looks good, but I want to see if someone has a more "angular" solution.

Comment: The angular way is to transform the response as done in that plunk: http://jsfiddle.net/roadprophet/YpvG7/

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the derived property for display purposes, you can create a display filter rather than loading up your model with redundant data:

```
app.filter('personFullName', function() {
  return function(person) {
    return person.name + " " + person.surname;
  };
})
```

Then reference the filter in your template:

```
<div>
  <p>{{person | personFullName}}</p>
  <p>- should match -</p>
  <p>{{person.name}} {{person.surname}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is interesting, but I think I would prefer to keep the virtual attribute into the model, so that I can access it in several views without having to deal with the filter in each of them.

Answer (score 1):

[Khanh TO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038244/virtual-attributes-in-ngresource/24206361#24206361) put me on the way to a working answer for me, but, as explained [in this Angular ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11201#issuecomment-76367339), in the interceptor, you have to handle and return `response.resource` instead of `response`.

Here is a solution (working for Angular 1.4):

```
app.factory('Person', ['$resource', function($resource) {

return $resource(
    'api/path/:personId',
    {personId: '@_id'},
    {
        update: {method: 'PUT'},
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            interceptor: {
                response: function(response) {
                    var resource = response.resource;
                    resource.fullname = resource.name + ' ' + resource.surname;
                    return resource;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```